# How can I get the benefits from a BigQuery partitioned table when the values to filter that column come out of a subquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, database-partitioning

I have a query like this:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018`
  WHERE wiki='en'
  AND title LIKE 'Goo%'
), min_date_calc AS (
  SELECT DATE(MIN(datehour)) FROM data WHERE datehour<'2018-01-05'
)


SELECT title, SUM(views) views
FROM data
WHERE 
  DATE(datehour) BETWEEN (SELECT * FROM min_date_calc) AND DATE_ADD((SELECT * FROM min_date_calc), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

This query either doesn't run, or doesn't use the partitions to prune the data queried - scanning the whole table instead. What can I do here?

(question based on a [comment on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/ebkgsr/partition_on_any_field_with_bigquery/fb6gb9g/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will only scan 2.86GB:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018`
  WHERE wiki='en'
  AND title LIKE 'Goo%'
)

SELECT title, SUM(views) views
FROM data
WHERE 
  DATE(datehour) BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-08' # 2.68 GB 
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

But that's because I had the dates as a constant. Similarly, a query like this will perform well too:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018`
  WHERE wiki='en'
  AND title LIKE 'Goo%'
), min_date AS (
    SELECT DATE('2018-01-01')
)


SELECT title, SUM(views) views
FROM data
WHERE 
  DATE(datehour) BETWEEN (SELECT * FROM min_date) AND DATE_ADD((SELECT * FROM min_date), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

This works well, as the date has been made a constant (even when inside a function).

To get these same benefits with a value which is not a constant, then we can use scripting to get all of the benefits:

```
DECLARE min_date DATE;

SET min_date = (
  WITH data AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018`
    WHERE wiki='en'
    AND title LIKE 'Goo%'
  )
  SELECT DATE(MIN(datehour)) FROM data WHERE datehour<'2018-01-04'
);

WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018`
  WHERE wiki='en'
  AND title LIKE 'Goo%'  
)

SELECT title, SUM(views) views
FROM data
WHERE 
  DATE(datehour) BETWEEN min_date AND DATE_ADD(min_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) # 2.68 GB 
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

Now we see two queries:

- The first one goes as over as much data as it needs to set the value of `min_date`.
- The second one uses 2.86GB as the previous did too - but now the value of `min_date` comes out of a dynamic query.